# File transfer using ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I have a chat application using ejabberd2. Now, I need to transfer file over chat message. I just configure `mod_proxy65` in the `ejabberd.cfg` file and open the port `7777`. But send file failed.

`myejabberd.cfg` settings

```
{mod_proxy65,  [
                  {ip, {118,132,178,95}},
                  {name, "SOCKS5 Bytestreams"},
                  {host, "proxy.amadoa.org"}
                 ]},
```

Anybody know how I enable `mod_proxy65` in ejabberd2? Do I need to install any additional modules here?

Help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What exactly happens when the file transfer fails? Try capturing the involved xmpp stanzas. It may reveal the underlying reason.

Comment: Hi Vks : can I have achat with you http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64981/ejabberd-with-mysql

Comment: @vks, Hi vks did you got the answer for sending file.If yes please post the answer.Having same issue

Answer (score 3):

Most people confuse host with hostname ejabberd configuration, hostname is where you should provide your public IP or www.domain.com, where host is the logical name that you give to your ejabberd server; it defaults to proxy.domain.com,

Moreover the IP address is the IP of the interface that Ejabberd listens, so, it should be local address. Llike:  `192.168.1.10` to listen on one interface, or `0.0.0.0` to listen on all the interaces, or `127.0.0.1` to allow local file transfers only.

**Example of configuration that worked for me:**

```
{mod_proxy65,  [
                  {host, "proxy.domain.com"}, %% defines the Jabber ID of service. If not specified, Jabber ID will be hostname of  the virtual host with the prefix 'proxy'.

                  %%{ip, {192,168,1,90}}, %% this line works, or use the below line
                  {ip, {0,0,0,0}}, %% 127.0.0.1 by default, make it 0.0.0.0 to listen on all interfaces, or the ip of specific interface

                  {hostname, "www.domain.com"}, % useful service run behind a NAT. default is value of ip option. Ex: "proxy.mydomain.org", "200.150.100.50"
                  {port, 7777}, %% Default, we don't need to add
                  {access, all}, %% Default, we don't need to add
                  {shaper, c2s_shaper}
                 ]},
```